# escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: upload, codeigniter-2

When I want to upload anything in any form I see the **Warning: escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons** message on my site. What can I do to fix this?

My framework is codeigniter final version.

Here is the full warning:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons

Filename: libraries/Upload.php
```

Answer (score 9):

The `@` operator will silence any PHP errors the function could raise. **You should never use it!**

Solutions:

1. Remove the `escapeshellarg` string from the `disable_functions` in `php.ini` file
2. Ask your host provider to remove Remove the `escapeshellarg` string from the `disable_functions` in php.ini file if you don't have an access to the `php.ini` file
3. make your own `escapeshellarg`. The function only escapes any single quotes in the given string and then adds single quotes around it.

   ```
   function my_escapeshellarg($input)
   {
       $input = str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $input);
       return '\''.$input.'\'';
   }
   ```

   and do something like this:

   ```
   // $cmd = 'file --brief --mime ' . escapeshellarg($file['tmp_name']) . ' 2>&1';
   $cmd = 'file --brief --mime ' . my_escapeshellarg($file['tmp_name']) . ' 2>&1';
   ```

   But what is best is to extend the `Upload.php` library and override the `_file_mime_type` function instead of changing on the core of CodeIgniter so that you will not lose it if you ever want to update CodeIgniter.

   Helpful links: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$cmd = 'file --brief --mime ' . @escapeshellarg($file['tmp_name']) . ' 2>&1';
```

Open Upload.php file from system/libraries folder and put `@` in front of `escapeshellarg($file['tmp_name'])` at line 1066
 and second thing upload this file under application/libraries folder that will be better, other wise no problem, you can replace system's Upload.php file.

Comment: Thank you, got this error today and your answer worked like a charm!

Comment: thats just ignore the warning

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the escapeshellarg string from the disable_functions at php.ini* file
2. Ask your hosting provider to remove the string above if you don't have an access to the php.ini* file
3. Change hosting provider which allows the running of the escapeshellarg function.

from this website: http://www.2by2host.com/articles/php-errors-faq/disabled_escapeshellarg/

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way to solve this issue is just move your application from `development` to `production`:

Open `index.php` in your application root and change

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

to

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```