# PHP escapeshellarg() Issue, with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384336/escapeshellarg-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons)

I've created an image upload system with PHP and it all works but I still get a warning:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons

Filename: libraries/Upload.php

Line Number: 1066
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of this without contacting Hosting provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `escapeshellarg` with `@escapeshellarg`.

Because, then you'd be suppressing any warning that function call gives.

Since

> it all works

<strike>Doing that shouldn't be a problem to your working code.</strike>

Note: using `@` to suppress warnings or errors is not recommended.

Comment: not quite true - with CodeIgniter's exceptions handling system, this will still generate an error... but as an idea, it's most likely safe to remove the escapeshellarg() function from there completely, since hosting is taking care of shell functions (by disallowing them)

Comment: Using @ is not recommended, simply because it can make debugging a nightmare.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter No, you are wrong. I just tried to call `dummy()` from my view, and like expected it generated fatal error. But when i called `@dummy()` I didn't get any **errors**. And, yes it is a bad practice but the OP specifically asked for it["_get rid_"].

Comment: @goldenparrot if you disable errors displaying via ini_set('display_errors', false) and set exception to E_ALL, this still shows an error for me - is this different for your tests? what CI version you're using?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter you probably meant that comment @ me. I am using the latest CI version from the site without **any** changes to it.

Comment: @goldenparrot yes, sorry... I'll double check on this, since this is an active bug report in their issue tracker and since it's not yet closed as invalid, I'd say it is a valid point...

Comment: @goldenparrot ok, this would be my mistake - the bug [I described](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349608/php-escapeshellarg-issue-with-codeigniter/12349679#comment16582293_12349679) stands, however when you use @ sign, PHP obviously suppresses error handlers completely and just continues... good to know :)

Comment: Thank you all for the help, it seems the @ works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You will have to contact your sys admin to enable that function for you, or use something else (that does not involve executing shell commands) for what you are trying to accomplish.