# Codeigniter Image uploading not working on online server

Tags: codeigniter, webserver, image-uploading

I have developed a Codeignter project working very smooth on Local machine (Wamp server) but after uploading it on my server(namecheap) am facing problem with uploading images.

I have check permission access and give 777 to all upload folders and code is pretty much clean and working on local WAMP.

then i also uploaded it on another server(godaddy) there it was saying:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons

Filename: libraries/Upload.php
```

tried this: [escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384336/escapeshellarg-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons)
but no luck it stop displaying error but still no uploading.

Anyone else had faced this issue too?

Comment: Ok solved it was error with escapeshellarg() resolved after asking to enabling it. :)

Comment: See this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384336/escapeshellarg-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons

Answer (score 0):

folder system > libraries
file Upload.php

```
$cmd = 'file --brief --mime ' . escapeshellarg($file['tmp_name']) . ' 2>&1';
```

remove this line