# File upload issue in CI

Tags: file-upload, codeigniter-2

I am using CI and facing a problem while uploading file.
It gives a message mentioned below.

==================================================
Severity: Warning

Message: escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons

Filename: libraries/Upload.php

## Line Number: 1066

In some answers, I found that it is a server issue and CI has nothing to do with it. Now, is there any way to upload file bypassing the escapeshellarg() or is there any libraries I can use that doesn't require escapeshellarg()?

Please help.

Comment: you can use normal file uloading functoin

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which specific version of CI you're using, but the latest version does a check for that function before using it.

Take a [look at the code here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Upload.php#L1219):

```
$cmd = function_exists('escapeshellarg')
    ? 'file --brief --mime '.escapeshellarg($file['tmp_name']).' 2>&1'
    : 'file --brief --mime '.$file['tmp_name'].' 2>&1';
```

I'd say either upgrade or update the code manually.

Comment: I used the latest version 2.1.3. The problem was in Upload.php library class. I found the answer in this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384336/escapeshellarg-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons