# Codeigniter "Unable to load the requested file: upload.php"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't have any idea on what's wrong here:

I have tried:

```
get_instance()->load->library('upload', $config);

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$this->load->library('upload'); $this->upload->initialize($config);
```

I always get

```
"Unable to load the requested file: upload.php"
```

The Upload.php file is where it should (system/libraries) and I have no idea at all on this error.
Works fine on localhost, but not on the server.

Maybe it's because CI is installed on a subdomain? For me all configs are set correctly on CI configs.

Upload.php is a CI class, and for some reason, it's not being found from a controller, and this is quite bizarre to me.

Any clues?

Comment: Did you ...  Create a folder at the root of your CodeIgniter installation called uploads and set its file permissions to 777?

Comment: You can check .htaccess  configuration for rewrites.

Comment: Nice tip on .htaccess redirects, but everything's quite right there as well. As for the folder permission hint, the upload never started to no folder permission issues there. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found the issues:

First: When trying to call an upload function on the controller, directly on the address bar, the error:

```
 "Unable to load the requested file: upload.php"
```

Is directly caused by no file being sent for the function, as I found while tailing the CI log file.

Also, for some reason, config would not work if loaded like this:

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Had to init the config like this:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

That was error one.

Nevertheless, my upload function wasn't working anyway. After investigating firebug console errors as I'm using angular to do the upload, I've found the second issue:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons

Filename: libraries/Upload.php
```

So a quick search on stack overflow got me the answer:

> $cmd = 'file --brief --mime ' . @escapeshellarg($file['tmp_name']) . '
>   2>&1';
>
> Open Upload.php file from system/libraries folder and put @ in front
>   of escapeshellarg($file['tmp_name']) at line 1066 and second thing
>   upload this file under application/libraries folder that will be
>   better, other wise no problem, you can replace system's Upload.php
>   file

As in [escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384336/escapeshellarg-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons)

So I have manually updated the upload.php file and voilá.

After all, upload.php needed a patch for a server setup incompatibility.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I've found (on Linux) there's sometimes loading issues if your filename starts with an uppercase, but you try and load using lowercase, or vice-versa (I can't remember if this was with libraries or not).

Also make sure you have `class Upload` and not `class upload`

Comment: Indeed, I've seen that before, but this was happening to a default CI class, not a custom one, so by all means, it was supposed to work by default.